# Why the sound effect does not work in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

Why the sound effect does not work in unity?
when I try to add a sound effect, it doesn't work
This is my script to move to the next scene using buttons:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator transition;

    public float transitionTime = 1f;
    


    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
        
    }

      public AudioClip impact;
    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int LevelIndex)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelIndex);
      AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(impact, transform.position);
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making the audio play, and then immediately loading in a different scene. The object that is playing the audioclip also unloads.

You could offset the two by making `NewGame()` a coroutine instead, with a small timed offset between the `PlayClipAtPoint()` call and the `LoadScene()` call.

Comment: How to make small timed offset ?

Comment: In a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) you can add `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f)`, which will make the code halt for 2 seconds before continuing.

Comment: When I want to do it, I get this error. Assets \ Scrips \ MeinMenu.cs (9.17): error CS1624: content "MeinMenu.NewGame ()" cannot be an iterator block because "void" is not an iterator interface type

Comment: Coroutines need to have `IEnumerator` as their return type and need to be called with `StartCoroutine(NewGame())` instead of just `NewGame()`.
I recommend checking the manual I linked to in my last comment.

Comment: I edited the question and
does this script look better now?
But unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: Try putting the `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(impact, transform.position);` before `yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);`
The `WaitForSeconds()` makes the thread wait for that amount of time, so you'd want to start playing the audio BEFORE that, then wait, and then load in the new scene.

Comment: is it possible to make the sound play during the scene transition animation? Because when I postpone it, the sound plays after the animation or not at all

Comment: I don't know what your scene transition logic looks like, so it's hard to tell. It also goes outside of the scope of this question imho.

Answer (score 0):

As `Alex Leest` said, you are loading new scene right after audio play.

When unity scene loading started, all gameobject except `DontDestroyOnLoad Object` are destroyed.

So, you may add code below to your Audio Manage class.
(Also, you should ensure that your Audio Manager class always has only one instance in your whole program for not cause bugs)

```
private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
```

Comment: Is it something like this? Because it's not working for me.public class MeinMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }
    public void NewGame()
    {
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level 1");
    }
    public void LoadGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
    }
}

Comment: The gameObject that has `AudioSource` should be not destroyed. Would you make simple script named `DontDestroyOnLoad` and put code in my post. And add component to the gameObject that has `AudioSource`.